# Context sensitive language with non deterministic turing machine

Tags: grammar, turing-machines, non-deterministic, context-sensitive-grammar

how can i show a language is context sensitive with a non deterministic turing machine?

i know that a language that is accepted by a Linear bound automaton (LBA ) is a context -sensitive language. And a LBA is a non-deterministic turing machine.

Any idea how can i relate all these and show that a language is context sensitive?

Comment: As you might have figured, The CSTheory.stackexchange demands research-level questions. However, math.stackexchange is very suitable for such questions. Also, they support LaTeX for decent formatting of answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As templatetypedef's answer has some flaws (which I will point out in a second in a comment), I give a quick answer to your question:

The language is context sensitive if (and only if) you can give a nondeterministic turing machine using linear space that defines L.

Let L = { a^n b^n a^n } for an arbitrary integer n; a^n here means n concatenations of the symbol a. This is a typical context sensitive language. Instead of giving a CSG, you can give a LBA to show that L is context sensitive:

The turing machine M 'guesses' (thanks to nondeterminism) n [in other words you may say 'every branch of the nondeterministic search tree tries out another n], and then checks whether the input matches a^n b^n a^n. You need log n cells to store n, the matching might need (if implemented trivially) another log n cells. As n + 2log n < 2n, this machine needs only linear space, and is therefore an LBA, hence L is context sensitive.

Comment: Is there a proof that NSPACE(n) = CSL?  I've never heard of this result, but it seems really cool!

Comment: Yes, it has been proven in 1969; I can't find a public paper that holds a proof, ComplexityZoo (a very nice reference for complexity class questions by Scott Aaronson) holds http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000069800322 as reference. Maybe Google spits out some other proof that is publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer, but since the context-sensitive languages are precisely those accepted by a linear-bounded automaton (a TM with O(n) space on its tape), the context-sensitive languages are precisely those in DSPACE(n).  Moreover, we know that [NTIME(n) = DSPACE(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTIME).  This means that if you can find a linear-time NTM that decides membership in some language L, that language must be context-sensitive.  However, there still might be a context-sensitive language that does not have a linear-time NTM (I don't know whether there is a definitive answer to this or whether this is an open problem), so this is not an exact characterization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As mentioned, this answer has some errors: On one hand we don't know whether DSPACE(n) is a subset of NTIME(n). The other way around is obvious. On the other hand, CSLs are precisely the languages in NSPACE(n), not DSPACE(n). It is an open problem, but believed that DSPACE(n) is a proper subset of NSPACE(n).